# In .NET Core if I want to do authorization, would it be better to use a middleware or an authorization filter?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In .NET Core if I want to do authorization, would it be better to use a middleware or an authorization filter ?

Please give reasons as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about ASP.NET Core MVC. Since v3.0 by default authorization is based on a middleware:

- From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorization) on migrating from v2.2 to v3.0 (Authorization):

> In earlier versions of ASP.NET Core, authorization support was provided via the `[Authorize]` attribute. Authorization middleware wasn't available. In ASP.NET Core 3.0, authorization middleware is required. We recommend placing the ASP.NET Core Authorization Middleware (`UseAuthorization`) immediately after `UseAuthentication`. The Authorization Middleware can also be configured with a default policy, which can be overridden.

> When using endpoint routing, we recommend against configuring `AuthorizeFilter` and instead relying on the Authorization middleware. If the app uses an `AuthorizeFilter` as a global filter in MVC, we recommend refactoring the code to provide a policy in the call to `AddAuthorization`.

- From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorization-filters) on filters:

> The built-in authorization filter:
>
> - **Calls the authorization system**.
> - Does not authorize requests.

- From code comments [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Authorization/AuthorizeFilter.cs#L148):

> When doing endpoint routing, MVC does not create filters for any authorization specific metadata i.e [Authorize] does not get translated into AuthorizeFilter.

- You can also see a proof [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.0/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs#L59) that the middleware uses `[Authorize]` attribute directly (the attribute implements `IAuthorizeData`)

I would add that you should only use filters when you need to make decisions based on some MVC context information not available in the middleware. Note that this makes sense only for custom authorization filters; the built-in authorization filter does basically the same as the middleware.

The middleware can apply authorization policies even to route handlers which know nothing about authorization (the docs mention health check functionality as an example). So it's much more flexible, broad and universal compared to authorization filters.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware fires sooner and has access to the request, filters fire later and can access things like routing logic. So "it depends", as always. Though I personally prefer middleware most of the time.

I prefer middleware for cases when the Auth is a simple allow/block for almost all endpoints in the app. It's simpler and exits faster. But, e.g., one of the apps I work on has granular access rules tied to specific users and roles pulled from a DbContext, with the routes themselves coming from the DB. In this case I'm using auth and action filters.